# Understanding the math of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, error-analysis

The Uncertainty principle is stated below:

$$\Delta x.\Delta p\geq\frac{h}{4\pi}\tag{1}$$

Now, if we decrease the uncertainty in position $(\Delta x)$, the uncertainty in momentum has to increase to preserve the validity of $(1)$.

Now, my question is, isn't it possible to decrease the uncertainty in position $(\Delta x)$ without changing the uncertainty in momentum $(\Delta p)$?

For example, in $xy\geq10$, if $x=10,y=10$, the inequality is true. If we decrease $x$ to $x=9$, the inequality is still true and $y$ doesn't need to be increased.

Can the same be applied to $(1)$?

Comment: If $\Delta x\Delta y$ is *strictly* larger than $\hbar/2$, then you can decrease one without increasing the other. It's only when the the two sides are *equal* that decreasing one requires an increase in the other.